# LuaTeX: function "node.effective_glue" returns 0 on \hfill and \vfill?

Tags: luatex

I would like to use LuaTeX's function `node.effective_glue` to get the real size of a \hfill or a \vfill but it returns 0 in both cases, what am I missing?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setlength{\textheight}{200pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{200pt}

\directlua{
  GLUE  = node.id("glue")
  HLIST = node.id("hlist")
  showglue=function(head)
    while (head) do
    if head.id == GLUE then
       local w = node.effective_glue(head) / 65536
       texio.write_nl('*VGlue: ' .. head.subtype .. ' ' .. tostring(w) .. 'pt')
    elseif head.id == HLIST then
       line = head.head
       for n in node.traverse_id(GLUE,line) do
         local w = node.effective_glue(n,line) / 65536
         texio.write_nl(' HGlue: ' .. n.subtype .. ' ' .. tostring(w) .. 'pt')
       end
    end
    head = head.next
    end
    return true
  end
luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_output_filter",showglue,"Show Glue")
}

\begin{document}
A\hskip 50pt\relax B\hfill C\par
\vskip 80pt\relax
M
\vfill
Z
\end{document}
```

The .log file shows:

```
*VGlue: 10 2.8399963378906pt % OK topskip
 HGlue: 0 50.0pt             % OK \hskip 50pt
 HGlue: 0 0.0pt              % \hfill ???
 HGlue: 15 0.0pt             % OK parfillskip
 HGlue: 9 0.0pt              % OK rightskip
*VGlue: 0 80.0pt             % OK \vskip 80pt
*VGlue: 3 0.0pt              % OK parskip
*VGlue: 2 4.9499969482422pt  % OK baselineskip
 HGlue: 15 0.0pt             % OK parfillskip
 HGlue: 9 0.0pt              % OK rightskip
*VGlue: 0 0.0pt              % \vfill ???
*VGlue: 3 0.0pt
*VGlue: 2 5.1699981689453pt
 HGlue: 15 0.0pt
 HGlue: 9 0.0pt
*VGlue: 0 0.0pt
```

Note: in the first call to `node.effective_glue` I pass only one argument, I have no idea of what the "parent" node should be. I get no error message though…

Comment: you need to pass the hlist representing the hbox containing the node as the second argument

Comment: for the h case you want        line = head  not        line = head.head but you are traversing in a strange order I'm not sure wheer you are in the other case:-)  when yoiu see an hlist you are just looking for glue so will skip over any glue in nested boxes, is that intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two cases are a bit different:

- At the point where `pre_output_filter` is executed, the content isn't boxed yet so you can't use `effective_glue` yet. (Since the parent doesn't exists)

  If you really need it you can use `tex.vpack` to build a vlist out of the list and then use the generated node as a parent. But take care since the list is still subject to change before it is finally shipped out.
- For the second case, you have to ensure that `parent` is the parent node (the hlist or vlist which contains the node), not the head of the list. In your case this means that you have to use `node.effective_glue(n,head)` instead of `node.effective_glue(n,line)`. (The naming is a bit confusing here since your `head` variable isn't fixed at the head)

Comment: Thanks! I understand my mistake in the second case. For the first case, my choice of `pre_output_filter` is probably wrong, can you suggest another callback in which the page content would be boxed? My question is related to my package lua-typo, I do not need to change anything to the page content, I just want to point out potential typographical flaws.

Comment: @DanielFlipo Starting with the next LaTeX release, there will be a new callback `pre_shipout-filter` available which provides you with the page box directly before it's shipped out. That might be useful but you will additionally have to deal with headers/footnotes/etc...

Comment: GREAT!  I was wondering why I couldn't check footnotes. Thanks *a lot*.